# Transfer touches from uiview to uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview (With image) in UIView (Red color).

UIView - {0,0, 320, 236} UIScrollview - {0, 8, 300, 220}

[image]

[image]

In my uiview, I got touches.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}
```

I need to transfer touch from UIView to UIScrollview. (e.g if user swipe from right side of uiview to left, uiscrollview should scroll to left in sync with user touch). May I know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to get a reference to your scrollView inside your UIView, calculate the x touches delta and adjust the contentOffset property of the scrollView accordingly.

So, in your UIView class:

```
@implementation MyView{
  CGPoint _startPosition;
  CGPoint _previousPosition;
}
```

Initialize the above variables in your

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  _startPosition = [touch locationInView:self];
  _previousPosition = _startPosition;
}
```

Then in your touchesMoved:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.scrollView];


if(!CGPointEqualToPoint(_previousPosition, _startPosition)){
    CGFloat deltaX = _previousPosition.x-currentPosition.x;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        //
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x +
                                                    deltaX, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    }];


}
_previousPosition = currentPosition;
}
```

The scrollView.contentOffset is adjusted in an animation block to make the scroll smooth.

Link to a working project: https://github.com/sliaquat/stack_overlfow_answer_28036976